# React native: event source is not closing after logout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, push-notification, server-sent-events

I want to close event source after user logout. My codes are below. When user logging out push notifications are still coming. My questions is how to close event source?

```
 const eventSource = new EventSource(`${environment.notificationUrl}/subscribe? 
  token=${token}`);

  if (!token) {
  eventSource.removeAllEventListeners()
  eventSource.close()
  return;
 }


 eventSource.addEventListener('message', (event: any) => {
 ---- some codes here ----
 }
```

Comment: which library do you use for EventSource, I have a problem using sse in react native. the message event never triggered @aytac

Answer (score 0):

Technically, event listeners should be subscribed inside `useEffect` and keep tracking when user logged out.

```js
const NotificationSubscriptionManager = () => {
  const eventSource =
    new EventSource(`${environment.notificationUrl}/subscribe? 
  token=${token}`);

  const subScribeToNotifications = () => {
    eventSource.addEventListener("message", (event: any) => {
      /// ---- some codes here ----
    });
  };

  const unsubScribeToNotifications = () => {
    eventSource.removeAllEventListeners();
    eventSource.close();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) {
      return unsubScribeToNotifications();
    }

    // Subscribe to notification events
    subScribeToNotifications();

    // Cancel all subscription when component unmount to avoid
    // memory leak

    return () => {
      unsubScribeToNotifications();
    };
  }, [token]);
};
```